# How can I check the validation of the LCID without try\catch block?

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo, lcid

Some types has the `TryParse` method, for example it is `Int32`, `Int64`, `Boolean`, etc. It allows check the string value without try\catch block. It very much influences on productivity when many incorrect values are processing in a cycle. I need to do the same for string value of the LCID. But the `CultureInfo` class has not the `TryParse` method.

```
CultureInfo culture = null;
try {
  culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Convert.ToInt32(lcid, 16));
}
catch {
}
```

How can I rewrite this code?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this code? If the framework provided such a method it would still have to try/catch. If you are concerned about the succinctness of the code then you could create an Extension method on the string type.

Comment: No, I am not concerned about the succinctness of the code. But it very much influences on productivity when many incorrect values are processing in a cycle. Here I showed some results about comparring `try\catch` variant and the `TryGetObjectId` (it is a some analogy of `TryParse`): https://sites.google.com/site/bushmansnetlaboratory/sendbox/stati/database/compare

 00:05:30,4050567 and 00:00:00,7027717. Big difference in productivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cache all the CultureInfo objects by LCID in a dictionary:

```
var culturesByLcid = CultureInfo
    .GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .ToDictionary(c => c.LCID, c => c);
```

and use TryGetValue like:

```
CultureInfo found;
if (culturesByLcid.TryGetValue(lcid, out found))
{
    ...
}
```